# Absinthe - How to put_session in resolver function?

Tags: graphql, elixir, session-cookies, phoenix-framework, absinthe

I'm using Absinthe and have a sign in mutation. When users send over valid credentials, I'd like to set a session cookie in the response via `put_session`.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to access the `conn` from within a resolver function. That tells me that I'm not supposed to update the connection's properties from within a resolver.

Is it possible to do this with Absinthe? What are some alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It looks like one solution is:

1. In the resolver, resolve either an `{:ok, _}` or an `{:error, _}` as normal
2. Add [middleware after the resolver](https://elixirforum.com/t/modify-absinthe-resolution-context-in-a-resolver/29602) to pattern match that `resolution.value` returned from step 1 and update the GraphQL context
3. Use the [before_send](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe_plug/Absinthe.Plug.html#module-before-send) feature of Absinthe (which has access to both the GraphQL context and the connection to `put_session` before sending a response

### Code Example

Mutation:

```
mutation do
  @desc "Authenticate a user."
  field :login, :user do
    arg(:email, non_null(:string))
    arg(:password, non_null(:string))
    resolve(&Resolvers.Accounts.signin/3)

    middleware(fn resolution, _ ->
      case resolution.value do
        %{user: user, auth_token: auth_token} ->
          Map.update!(
            resolution,
            :context,
            &Map.merge(&1, %{auth_token: auth_token, user: user})
          )

        _ ->
          resolution
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

Resolver:

```
defmodule AppWeb.Resolvers.Accounts do
  alias App.Accounts

  def signin(_, %{email: email, password: password}, _) do
    if user = Accounts.get_user_by_email_and_password(email, password) do
      auth_token = Accounts.generate_user_session_token(user)
      {:ok, %{user: user, auth_token: auth_token}}
    else
      {:error, "Invalid credentials."}
    end
  end
end
```

Router:

```
defmodule AppWeb.Router do
  use AppWeb, :router

  pipeline :api do
    plug(:accepts, ["json"])
    plug(:fetch_session)
  end

  scope "/" do
    pipe_through(:api)

    forward("/api", Absinthe.Plug,
      schema: AppWeb.Schema,
      before_send: {__MODULE__, :absinthe_before_send}
    )

    forward("/graphiql", Absinthe.Plug.GraphiQL,
      schema: AppWeb.Schema,
      before_send: {__MODULE__, :absinthe_before_send}
    )
  end

  def absinthe_before_send(conn, %Absinthe.Blueprint{} = blueprint) do
    if auth_token = blueprint.execution.context[:auth_token] do
      put_session(conn, :auth_token, auth_token)
    else
      conn
    end
  end

  def absinthe_before_send(conn, _) do
    conn
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like a smart solution to me. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you. Still, it's a bit more complex than I would like so I'll likely keep the authentication layer outside of GraphQL (and use REST instead).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to use a session, can't this be solved using a bearer?

Please disregard the interfaces. :-)

Mutation.

```
  object :user_token_payload do
    field(:user, :user)
    field(:token, :string)
  end

  object :login_user_mutation_response, is_type_of: :login_user do
    interface(:straw_hat_mutation_response)

    field(:errors, list_of(:straw_hat_error))
    field(:successful, non_null(:boolean))
    field(:payload, :user_token_payload)
  end
```

Resolver.

```
  def authenticate_user(args, _) do
    case Accounts.authenticate_user(args) do
      {:ok, user, token} -> MutationResponse.succeeded(%{user: user, token: token})
      {:error, message} -> MutationResponse.failed(StrawHat.Error.new(message))
    end
  end
```

Now the client can pass along that token with the Authorization header, and pick it up with a plug.

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Plugs.Context do
  import Plug.Conn
  alias MyApp.Admission

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _) do
    case build_context(conn) do
      {:ok, context} -> put_private(conn, :absinthe, %{context: context})
      _ -> put_private(conn, :absinthe, %{context: %{}})
    end
  end

  @doc """
  Return the current user context based on the authorization header
  """
  def build_context(conn) do
    auth_header =
      get_req_header(conn, "authorization")
      |> List.first()

    if auth_header do
      "Bearer " <> token = auth_header

      case Admission.get_token_by_hash(token) do
        nil -> :error
        token -> {:ok, %{current_user: token.user}}
      end
    else
      :error
    end
  end
end
```

Then add the plug to your pipeline

```
plug(MyApp.Plugs.Context)
```

Then you can pick up the current user in your resolvers like so.

```
  def create_note(%{input: input}, %{context: %{current_user: user}}) do
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this alternative solution using Bearer tokens. As I understand, using Bearer tokens requires clients to store them in local storage, which could open up the application to more XSS attacks. Going with the HTTP only cookie approach, that problem goes away (and introduces CSRF attacks, which [this document helps solve](https://dev.to/rtfeldman/defense-against-the-dark-arts-csrf-attacks)).